# Where can I find a complete list of every D&D book ever released before 3rd Edition?

Tags: adnd-1e, odnd

Where can I find a complete list of every D&D book ever released before 3rd Edition?

Is there such a thing?

I'm mostly interested in the supplement material like modules and the hardcover supplements, not things like playing cards or dungeon tiles or anything like that. Just the books.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily search for that on RPGGeek, which has a comprehensive database of all RPG products.  [Here's the search for D&D](http://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=rpg&q=dungeons+and+dragons&B1=Go), and you can then drill down by version and filter by product type if you don't want cards and whatnot.  Or given your specific needs, the RPG.net database [distinguishes AD&D out from D&D](http://index.rpg.net/display-generalinfo.phtml?key=system&value=AD%26D). That includes second edition.

Comment: RPGGeek was no help for second edition, but RPG.net has one heck of a comprehensive list! Thanks! This plus the Acaeum should fill in all the gaps.

Comment: Hm?  AD&D Second Edition search page on RPGGeek: http://rpggeek.com/rpg/244/advanced-dungeons-dragons-2nd-edition

Answer (score 7):

The Acaeum

- Rulebooks: http://acaeum.com/ddindexes/rulebooks.html
- Modules: http://acaeum.com/ddindexes/modcode.html
- Miscelleaneous: http://acaeum.com/ddindexes/misc.html
- "The Rares" http://acaeum.com/ddindexes/rares.html

Comment: Is 2nd Edition AD&D there? I don't see it.

Comment: You are right, 2nd edition does not seem to be included.

Comment: Thanks anyways, that is 75% of the information I was looking for.

Comment: +1 - Yay for the Acaeum, a love bunch of chaps (and chapesses)

Answer (score 4):

There are also lists of D&D rulebooks and modules in the English Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_rulebooks

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_modules

Answer (score 3):

There's also a PDF checklist that's pretty good: [Dungeons & Dragons Collectors Checklist, by Richard](https://img.fireden.net/tg/image/1445/62/1445623982414.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

See also the Acaeum Wiki which is maintained by other people and does include a pretty comprehensive coverage of 2nd edition. See http://wiki.acaeum.com/wiki/Category:Advanced_Dungeons_and_Dragons_2nd_Edition

Comment: Link is broken sometime within the last decade that this was posted.